# Ubuntu 13.04 not booting after clean installation

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04, grub2, partitioning

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.04 but it doesnt boot (I'm using "try ubuntu" option).

I downloaded the iso that corresponds to my computer (amd x64) and I made a USB device bootable using the Universal USB Installer as http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows suggests. The installation went perfectly but after rebooting my computer without the USB device a black screen appears with the next message: **"Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key"** and I can't get out of there!! I have read many posts all over the internet with a similar problem and I have tried many things such as reinstalling Ubuntu (kinda obvious), redownloading and reburning to the USB and reinstalling (or at least I tried) again and I can't get the problem solved.

I have also tried using Boot Repair and it was supossed to fix my problem but it didn't, I ran the Recommended Repair and this is the link it generated: paste.ubuntu.com/5942067. I thing I'm getting crazy lol

**This are the specs of my computer:**

- Motherboard: ASUS M5A97
- Processor: AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 960T Processor × 4
- RAM: 4GB

**And this is how I specify the partitions:**
* EFI Partition: 60MB beginning primary

- /boot: 100MB beginning primary ext4
- swap: 2GB beginning logic
- / : 70GB beginning logic ext4
- /home: 179GB beginning logic ext4

As a detail I used to have Ubuntu 12.04 and I never had any trouble. After that I tried Debian and Fedora but now I want to get back to Ubuntu but now 13.04

I hope someone can help me please!! D:

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have to reinstall. Use a 64bit disk of Ubuntu. Set up your firmware (BIOS) to boot the disk in UEFI mode.

In your BIOS, disable QuickBoot/FastBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT). If you have Windows8, also disable FastStartup.

Boot your PC using the LiveDVD or LiveUSB and choose "Try Ubuntu". If you get a Secure boot or signature error, you may wish to disable SecureBoot as described here, then retry to boot the disk.

If the other systems (Windows Vista/7/8, GNU/Linux...) of your computer are installed in EFI mode, then you must install Ubuntu in EFI mode too.

If the other systems (Windows, GNU/Linux...) of your computer are installed in Legacy (not-EFI) mode, then you must install Ubuntu in Legacy mode too. Eg if your computer is old (<2010), is 32bits, or was sold with a pre-installed Windows XP.

Partitioning:
Mount point: /boot/efi (remark: no need to set this mount point when using the manual partitioning, the Ubuntu installer will detect it automatically)

Size: minimum 100Mib. 200MiB recommended.

Type: FAT32

Other: needs a "boot" flag.

Source:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting